# How to turn a function of 3 nested loops into one recursive function?

Tags: c++, c

what would the recursive version for the following function would be like:

```
void tri_loop(size_t i, size_t j, size_t k)
{
    for(size_t x = 0; x < i; ++x)
        for(size_t y = 0; y < j; ++y)
            for(size_t z = 0; z < k; ++z)
            {
                cout << x <<y << z;
            }
}
```

**Just for mental drilling.**(Edit: emphasized this line)

Comment: why is everyone using size_t nowadays instead of good old  (and shorter) int

Comment: My first thought is that, making this function recursive would introduce static variables and a lot more code (if statements etc). It seems like this function might be better designed as three nested loops.

Comment: Since cout is the only C++-specific feature used here, this could be tagged as C too.

Comment: @reinier: _In this concrete case:_ From the code shown, I would have used `unsigned int` - except that the parameters passed (presumably due to constraints in some parts of the code we aren't shown) are `size_t` (actually `std::size_t`) and they are used as loop constraints. _In general:_ When accessing arrays, `std::size_t` is just the type that _should_ be used. I guess the STL's ubiquitous `size_type` made people aware of that.

Comment: still there is a tension I'm feeling. The main reason for someone to do something in C++ is that the result is fast, otherwise why not go with a nicer, cleaner and more forgiving language. Anyhow, is speed is your thing, you have to know the datatypes in advance (so size of int, size of char, etc) otherwise you end up going through loops making your code as portable as can be (and thus sacrificing speed). size_t feels like yet another datatype whose size is unknown and presumable is intended for portability and thus sacrificing speed. So speed vs portability is the tension I'm feeling here

Comment: @reinier - There should be no loss of speed in using `size_t`. It is inherited from C, and will be `typedef`-ed to the appropriate basic integral datatype for storing array sizes and indexing arrays - usually `unsigned int` or `unsigned long` depending on your platform. There will be no more performance penalty for using `size_t` than in using the raw appropriate data type in your code, except that the appropriate data type will be less portable. Speed is important, but there's no performance penalty here at all. I don't know why you're feeling any tension.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
void recurse(accumulator,b,c,d,limit)
{
  if (limit == 0)
    printf("%i %i %i\n", b, c, d);
  else
    if (accumulator<limit)
    {
      recurse(accumulator+1,b,c,d,limit);
      recurse(0,accumulator,b,c,d);
    }
}

main()
{
  int x=2,y=3,z=4;
  recurse(0,0,x,y,z);
}
```

Is that recursive enough?

Comment: if this actually works, then bonus points for the most mindf***er of them all

Comment: This compiles fine with gcc.  I have taken some dubious shortcuts with my function typing - add ints in the argument list if your compiler complains.

Comment: I test it and it works! you've indeed drilled a big hole in my head.

Answer (score 4):

I think something like this:

```
void tri_loop_work(size_t i, size_t imax, size_t j, size_t jmax, size_t k, size_t kmax)
{
  std::cout << "i=" << i << ", j=" << j << ", k=" << k << std::endl;
  if(k < kmax)
    tri_loop_work(i, imax, j, jmax, k + 1, kmax);
  else if(j < jmax)
    tri_loop_work(i, imax, j + 1, jmax, 0, kmax);
  else if(i < imax)
    tri_loop_work(i + 1, imax, 0, jmax, 0, kmax);
}

void tri_loop(size_t imax, size_t jmax, size_t kmax)
{
  tri_loop_work(0, imax, 0, jmax, 0, kmax);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of would be to be split it in to four functions as follows:

```
void tri_loop(size_t j, size_t k, size_t K) {
    tri_loopX(0,i,j,k);
}

void tri_loopX(size_t x, size_t i, size_t j, size_t k) {
    if (x >= i) {
        return;
    } else {
        tri_loopY(x, 0, j, k);
        tri_loopX(++x, i, j, k);
    }
}

void tri_loopY(size_t x, size_t y, size_t j, size_t k) {
    if (y >= j) {
        return;
    } else {
         tri_loopZ(x, y, 0, k);
         tri_loopY(x, ++y, j, k); 
    }
}

void tri_loopZ(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z, size_t k) {
    if (z >= k) {
        return;
    } else {
        cout << x << y << z;
        tri_loopZ(x, y, ++z, k);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This first version is much more efficient in terms of stack space than a naiive approach passing all the variables between the recursive calls (in fact, you should be able to calculate 3 times as deep (if you can figure out why).

```
struct State {
    size_t x, y, z;
};

struct Limits {
    size_t i, j, k;
};

void tri_loop(struct State *s, const struct Limits *l)
{
    if (s->z == l->k) {
        s->y++;
        s->z = 0;
    }
    if (s->y == l->j) {
        s->x++;
        s->y == 0;
    }
    if (s->x == l->i + 1)
        return;

    cout << s->x << s->y << s->z;
    s->z++;
    tri_loop(s, l);
}
```

Another approach, if you want to maintain state independence between the recursive calls would be to pass x, y, & z individually between the calls:

```
tri_loop(x, y, z + 1, l);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GCC:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void tri_loop(size_t ii, size_t jj, size_t kk)
{
  void tri_loop_inner(size_t i, size_t j, size_t k)
  {
    printf("i=%d j=%d k=%d \n", i, j, k);

    if(k < kk)
        tri_loop_inner(i,j,k+1);
    else if(j < jj)
        tri_loop_inner(i,j+1,0);
    else if(i < ii)
        tri_loop_inner(i+1,0,0);
  }

  tri_loop_inner(0, 0, 0);
}

int main()
{

        tri_loop(3,3,3);
        return 0;
}
```

It's not C++, and it's not even proper C, but it's been bothering me ever since I saw unwind's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to write a class, just to cut down on the parameter lists really.

```
class tri_loop_tool
{
  private:
    size_t x, y, z;
    size_t i, j, k;

    void Over_z ();
    void Over_y ();
    void Over_x ();

  public:
    void operator() (size_t pi, pj, pk);
};

void tri_loop_tool::Over_z ()
{
  if (z < k)
  {
    cout << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << endl;
    z++;    Over_z ();
  }
}

void tri_loop_tool::Over_y ()
{
  if (y < j)
  {
    z = 0;  Over_z ();
    y++;    Over_y ();
  }
}

void tri_loop_tool::Over_x ()
{
  if (x < i)
  {
    y = 0;  Over_y ();
    x++;    Over_x ();
  }
}

void tri_loop_tool::operator() (size_t pi, pj, pk)
{
  i = pi; j = pj; k = pk;
  x = 0;  Over_x ();
}
```

Note that this is using tail recursion - if you're lucky, your compiler might optimise it into iteration. Even so, the original three loops version is better in several ways than this - readability, efficiency, ...

I *have* used this method in real code, but not for anything this simple.